# PHP: Listen for HTTP-request / HTTP streaming

Tags: php, ajax, http, streaming

Recently I've been reading a little about Ajax HTTP streaming. If I understood everything well HTTP streaming is achieved by sending an Ajax request to the server. The server starts a PHP script, and that script just won't terminate, but will flush it's content regularly so the browser can receive any output.

However, when many clients connect to a server using HTTP streaming it will consume quite some memory, since each connection needs it's own PHP process. So I was thinking, is it perhaps possible to have one PHP script which listens to any incoming HTTP requests? In that case that script can handle multiple connections and it will therefore save memory. And if this is possible, what are the downsides to this method? And are there any other methods available?

Note: currently I don't have a real world example for this, I'm just experimenting with this.

Comment: Yes it's possible that one PHP process can listen to multiple HTTP requests, you find multiple components to do so in the [Application Server in PHP](https://github.com/indeyets/appserver-in-php/wiki). Take care because PHP is not the best-choice of language for doing  mutli-concurrency and multi-threaded HTTP streaming.

Comment: I agree with @hakre in that PHP is definitely not the language for this. You really need a language with controllable multithreading and synchronisation. I would go with Java, but that is just personal preference.

Comment: You'd have to listen for HTTP requests on a different port to port 80 also. Are you trying to emulate WebSockets?

Comment: If you want to try this in PHP you could look into the ØMQ library for handling the connections (http://www.zeromq.org/).

Comment: _hakre, Dave_ - I was already afraid of that since I couldn't find much about this subject for PHP. _N.B._ - Unfortunately WebSockets aren't implemented by many browsers yet, but that is more or less what I was looking for! _cgwyllie_ - That seems really nice as well! thanks!

Comment: I've recently been looking into node.js and that seems quite nice for these kind of things. I wouldn't use it to construct entire webpages, but I think it is quite usefull for Ajax based applications.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you refer to is called push vs. pull notification. Pull - is when the client is sending a request to the server - and the server responses, and push - is when the server initiate the communication.

It sounds to me that you're looking for a "push" solution. Use the following link to see how you can setup UDP connection:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-create.php

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. Of course I'm talking about push, that was the Ajax bit I was talking about;) My question is if it's possible to let multiple clients (browsers) connect to one php process. Using socket_create I can only connect to other domains, not to clients, and the php script needs to start the connection instead of the client.

Comment: Ajax is not Push, Ajax is Pull. I don't understand the design: the php process should start all the browsers ?

another really simple PULL implementation is using JS with setTimeout()

Comment: No, the php process shouldn't start the browser. The Ajax type of streaming I was talking about is calling a PHP script from the browser using Ajax (indeed, pull), however instead of running the php script and closing it, the PHP script gets in an infinite while loop, and constantly checks if there is some new data to be returned. When there is new data, the PHP script echo's the data and flushes it's buffer so the webapplication will receive the content (push). However, this requires every connection between browser and server to have it's own process running... (continue in next comment)

Comment: So with many connections, there are many processes which do next to nothing most of the time, and are just sitting in memory. So I wanted to know if it is possible to have a php script running which waits for HTTP requests, instead of being started by an HTTP request. If this is possible, I can have one script running which handles multiple connections to browsers, instead of one script per connection.

Comment: @Tiddo any php script that you'll run on apache - will be able to handle multiple connections.

Comment: Well, one script can be executed multiple times, but executing a script one time which handles multiple connections is a totally different thing. That is something which apparently isn't that easy in php

Comment: but why do you want the same script to handle multiple connections ? the same script can check the DB and "see" information related to the other connections, if needed. there are two things I think your should consider: first, if you can achieve the same results without "handling the connections" - this should be the best. if not, you probably want to use a "lower level" programming language like java or c++.

Comment: Since the only other pure PHP option is to run one process per connection, as usual with Ajax. However with long living connections this will cost a lot of resources for my modest VPS;) But I'm indeed convinced that I should use a different programming language for this. Either something like java or c++, or perhaps even node.js, which seems quite suited for the job as well.

Comment: I heard good things about node.js but I can't recommend about it myself since I didn't use it. please update this thread if you use it and tell us how you did it and if you were pleased with node.js!

Comment: I will! It might take some time, since I'm very busy at the moment, but I will update this thread;)

Comment: It turns out that Node.js is designed for these kind of things. There is a really nice package called socket.io for node, which can be used to create a (web)socket connection from the client to the server. It is really easy to implement HTTP streaming with this. Check http://socket.io/ for examples.